# curl: server certificate verification failed

Tags: curl, ssl

На сайте установле SSL сертификат, браузер его видит и поддерживает.

[image: SSL сертификат]

Но curl при попытке загрузки адреса выдаёт ошибку:

```
mcfinley@mcfinley-Lenovo-G570:~$ curl --cert-status https://***.com
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Аналогично на PHP:

Допустим я запущу такой код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://мой-домен.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ( $output === FALSE ) {
  var_dump(curl_error($ch));
} else {
  var_dump($output);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Результатом будет `string(63) "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`

Comment: Покажите ваш код CURL

Comment: `curl --cert-status https://домен-моего-сайта.com`

Comment: Вы через SSH делаете запрос? вы просто проверяете сертификат или отправляете какие то  данные на данный ресурс ?

Comment: Обычный get запрос с помощью curl'a, никаких данных, без SSH. Если я задаю вопрос неправильно, поправьте меня. Я просто открываю терминал, пишу `curl https://домен-моего-сайта.com` и получаю сообщение, приведенное в теле вопроса: 
`curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`

Comment: Затрудняюсь вам помочь, т.к сам никогда не пробовал запустить CURL именно через терминал(CMD), только посредством PHP->curl. Возможно найдутся знатоки ))

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: да я тоже проверил у себя, таже ошибка 63 или 60,  внятно непонять что тут ))
может поможет   http://serverfault.com/questions/755248/curl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-how-to-debug